# what is the difference between block scalar and flow scalar in yaml?

Tags: yaml

In [yaml spec](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) page, what is the difference between Example 2.14 and 2.18? Or are they just different ways of expressing the same content?

Answer (score 2):

[6.5 Line folding](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2779048) ways are diferrent. There are "Block Folding" and "Flow Folding".

```ruby
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

require 'yaml'

yaml = <<'EOT'
  A
  B
    C

  D

EOT

# 7.3.3. Plain Flow Scalar Style
p YAML.load_documents("---\n#{yaml}")

# 8.1.3. Folded Block Scalar Style
p YAML.load_documents("--- >\n#{yaml}")

# 8.1.2. Literal Block Scalar Style
p YAML.load_documents("--- |\n#{yaml}")
```

The results are:

```
["A B C\nD"]
["A B\n  C\n\nD\n"]
["A\nB\n  C\n\nD\n"]
```

Comment: Spot on -- put simply, `>` and `|` care about indentation and the alternative ([example 2.18](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#:~:text=Example%202.18%20Multi%2Dline%20Flow%20Scalars)) does not